# Automounting in ro mode (or with any options) NTFS partitions fails

Tags: usb, ntfs, automount, read-only

It seems that it has been more than a year since this bug has been fixed:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1180663

When can we expect an update in the Ubuntu distros?

I spent about half a day trying to debug why I cannot automount ntfs file systems in read only mode.

This bug report helped me and running automount interactively with -f -v options helped me figure out the problem.

I wanted to report my fix in an appropriate forum so I asked this question more in order to report a possible immediate bad fix. Maybe someone has a better one that they can report so other people don't spend the time I did poking around.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was this:
mv /bin/ntfs-3g /bin/ntfs-3g.bin
and replaced it with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ntfs:*=$@"
p1=$1
echo "ntfs:p1=$p1"
shift
p2="$1"
echo "ntfs:p2=$p2"
shift
echo "ntfs:1=$1"
test "$1" == "-s" && shift
echo "ntfs:1=$1"
exec /bin/ntfs-3g.bin $p1 "$p2" $@
```

This seems to take care of the problem.
I am devising a system where an unattended laptops mounts and unmounts devices attached and detached from it's usb ports automatically to a folder shared via samba on the local network.
So far here is what I have:

```
apt-get install autofs
```

add this to auto.master:

```
<root path here> program:/etc/auto.usb.prg ro
```

The "ro at the end is what requires the ntfs fix. Without it all is fine, but the drives are mounted r/w and unplugging them without umount (which is not possible in an unattended laptop, with no UI) is unsafe.

Put this into /etc/auto.usb.prg

```
#!/bin/bash
# - confuses grep. I do not know why automount asks for this key sometimes.
test "$1" == "-" && exit
devData=`blkid|grep "$1\|${1/_/ }"`
# determining fstype as auto seems to not work well.
t=${devData##*TYPE=\"}
t=${t%%\"*}
echo "-fstype=$t :${devData%%:*}"
```

I created this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/85-usbdrive-sharing.rules

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="carols_autommount_end"
DEVPATH!="*block/sd[b-z]/sd[b-z][1-9]", GOTO="carols_autommount_end"
# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"

ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", RUN+="/bin/ls '/home/sftpuser/extern/%E{ID_FS_LABEL}'", GOTO="carols_autommount_end"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", RUN+="/bin/ls /home/sftpuser/extern/%k"
# Exit
LABEL="carols_autommount_end"
```

I am having now trouble with removing the directories when the devices are unplugged. The rules could be rewrittend to send killall -USR1 automount on device removal. If at this time no clients are using the device, it will be unmounted.